# How to make curl print the request and response both in the terminal or output file

Tags: curl, http-post, http-get

I'm using curl to post a RPC in xml in my file `command.xml`. I am successfully receiving a response on terminal or file. The problem is that I want to see the request too with response. Is there a way to make curl echo my request's xml and the then response?

```
curl -X POST -k -g -6 -u "XXX@abc.com:Shanewarne" -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -d @command.xml https://[IPV6]:7443/Path
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/291424/how-do-you-display-post-data-with-curl